# How to get desired XML ouput from two XMLs using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, tridion

I am using XSLT and XML.

First thing I am going to work on two xml.

**First XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tcm:ListItems xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" ID="tcm:232-83752-2" Managed="10682">  
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:232-564598" Title="010 News Mapping"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:232-564599" Title="020 CUGOs"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:232-614307" Title="030 Reserved Urls"/>
</tcm:ListItems>
```

The **Second XML** we will get it using above ID i.e. tcm:232-564598 etc, below is one of the xml for ID tcm:232-564598 and other IDs will be having same type of XML.

```
<tcm:Component ID="tcm:229-564598" IsEditable="false" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <tcm:Data>
    <tcm:Content>
      <MappingCollection xmlns="uuid:922EEC29-2DE3-4BA1-A46A-A300CB8FA85F">
        <VanityUrl>
          <old>mbp</old>
          <new>/SessionHandler.aspx?pageurl=/BP.aspx&amp;pub=/english&amp;section=IBE&amp;j=f</new>
          <dateAdded>2010-05-03T14:45:00</dateAdded>
          <comments> News mapping </comments>
        </VanityUrl>
        <VanityUrl>
          <old>about/news</old>
          <new>about/news/news.aspx</new>
          <dateAdded>2010-05-03T14:45:00</dateAdded>
          <comments> News mapping </comments>
        </VanityUrl>
      </MappingCollection>
    </tcm:Content>
  </tcm:Data>
</tcm:Component>
```

I trying to get below format XML using above both XMLs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings>
    <!-- News mapping -->
    <mapping old="mbp" new="/SessionHandler.aspx?pageurl=/BP.aspx&amp;pub=/english&amp;section=IBE&amp;j=f"/>
    <mapping old="about/news" new="about/news/news.aspx"/>
    <!-- CUGO's-->
    <mapping old="/nhs" new="/cugo.aspx?promoCode=UKNHS01&amp;pub=/uk/english"/>
    <mapping old="/hk/ukstudentfare" new="/cugo.aspx?promoCode=HKSTU10&amp;pub=/hk/Chinese"/>
</mappings>
```

And Here is my XSLT where I am trying to generated the above format XML but it is not working for me. please note first xml is primary xml which will be transformed using below XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:em="http://www.espire.com/tridion/schemas" xmlns:tcmse="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.1/TcmScriptAssistant" exclude-result-prefixes="em xlink tcmse tcm">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" indent="yes"/>
  <!-- root match-->
  <xsl:template match="tcm:ListItems">
    <mappings>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tcm:Item"/>
    </mappings>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="tcm:Item">
      <xsl:variable name="doc" select="document(@ID)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$doc/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:MappingCollection/em:VanityUrl/em:comments">
      <xsl:comment>
        <xsl:value-of select="$doc/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:MappingCollection/em:VanityUrl/em:comments"/>
      </xsl:comment>
    </xsl:if>  
    <xsl:for-each select="$doc/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:MappingCollection/em:VanityUrl">
        <xsl:element name="mapping">
          <xsl:if test="$doc/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:MappingCollection/em:VanityUrl/em:old">
            <xsl:attribute name="old">
              <xsl:value-of select="$doc/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:MappingCollection/em:VanityUrl/em:old"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="$doc/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:MappingCollection/em:VanityUrl/em:new">
            <xsl:attribute name="new">
              <xsl:value-of select="$doc/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:MappingCollection/em:VanityUrl/em:new"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="$doc/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:MappingCollection/em:VanityUrl/em:dateAdded">
            <xsl:attribute name="dateAdded">
              <xsl:value-of select="$doc/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:MappingCollection/em:VanityUrl/em:dateAdded"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In above xslt I am able to get the data loop is also going correct but the data which is been coming is same, I mean loop is performing correct, but the node value is same

Please Suggest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ns="uuid:922EEC29-2DE3-4BA1-A46A-A300CB8FA85F"
 xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 exclude-result-prefixes="ns tcm msxsl">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="kVanityByComment" match="ns:VanityUrl" use="ns:comments"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="vSourcesRTF">
            <xsl:copy-of select="document(tcm:ListItems/tcm:Item/@ID)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <mappings>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($vSourcesRTF)/node()"/>
        </mappings>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns:VanityUrl"/>
    <xsl:template match="ns:VanityUrl[generate-id()=
                                      generate-id(key('kVanityByComment',
                                                      ns:comments)[1])]">
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns:comments"/>
        </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kVanityByComment',
                                         ns:comments)"
                             mode="output"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns:VanityUrl" mode="output">
        <mapping>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </mapping>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns:VanityUrl/ns:comments" priority="1"/>
    <xsl:template match="ns:VanityUrl/*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<tcm:ListItems xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" ID="tcm:232-83752-2" Managed="10682">
  <tcm:Item ID="229-564598" Title="010 News Mapping"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="229-564598" Title="020 CUGOs"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="229-564598" Title="030 Reserved Urls"/>
</tcm:ListItems>
```

And this external source with `229-564598` URI:

```
<tcm:Component ID="tcm:229-564598" IsEditable="false" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <tcm:Data>
    <tcm:Content>
      <MappingCollection xmlns="uuid:922EEC29-2DE3-4BA1-A46A-A300CB8FA85F">
        <VanityUrl>
          <old>mbp</old>
          <new>/SessionHandler.aspx?pageurl=/BP.aspx&amp;pub=/english&amp;section=IBE&amp;j=f</new>
          <dateAdded>2010-05-03T14:45:00</dateAdded>
          <comments> News mapping </comments>
        </VanityUrl>
        <VanityUrl>
          <old>about/news</old>
          <new>about/news/news.aspx</new>
          <dateAdded>2010-05-03T14:45:00</dateAdded>
          <comments> News mapping </comments>
        </VanityUrl>
      </MappingCollection>
    </tcm:Content>
  </tcm:Data>
</tcm:Component>
```

Output:

```
<mappings>
    <!-- News mapping -->
    <mapping old="mbp" 
             new="/SessionHandler.aspx?pageurl=/BP.aspx&amp;pub=/english&amp;section=IBE&amp;j=f"
             dateAdded="2010-05-03T14:45:00"></mapping>
    <mapping old="about/news"
             new="about/news/news.aspx"
             dateAdded="2010-05-03T14:45:00"></mapping>
</mappings>
```

**EDIT**: Multiple input sources.

Comment: Many Thanks Alejandro, it working perfectly with second xml independently, can you please have a look to my added code and suggest how I can incorporate it with your xslt.

Comment: @MKS: All the documents refered by first XML will be of just one type (i.e all `VanityUrl` with `comments='News mapping'`)?

Comment: Thanks, but sorry I didn't understand your point, can you please elaborate it,yes the format will be same but there can be many comments like "New Mapping", "cugos" etc. If you see the first xml there is an attribute ID from which its document will be loaded for every node <xsl:template match="tcm:Item">
    <xsl:variable name="doc" select="document(@ID)"/>
after this second xml comes in then above xslt code will be performed

Comment: @MKS: In those refered documents like "Second XML", all the `comments` elemets will be the same for each document (i.e. one document with all `comments` equal to "New Mapping", other document with all `comments` equal to "cugos") or there would be mixed `comemnts` elements type?

Comment: @Alej: +1 for inferring the OP's not-obvious requirement for grouping, and for Muenchian grouping. Regarding `old="{ns:old}"`, @MKS appears to want to omit these attributes completely if the child element is absent in the input.

Comment: @Alej there can be mixed comments in second xml

Comment: Guys my question is again different, did you all saw my example code, you can see there is I am working with both the xmls, however @Alej is only working with second xml and I am again saying that its working perfectly with second xml, I just want to incorporate this code to work with my first and second xml both.

Comment: Why did you kept same ID for each node in input, this ID will not be same, it will be unique. Please see my first XML, you changed that with this <tcm:Item ID="229-564598" Title="010 News Mapping"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="229-564598" Title="020 CUGOs"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="229-564598" Title="030 Reserved Urls"/>

Comment: @MKS: I'm lazy. I don't want to built two more input source and pollute this answer with them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the change you made is indeed critical. :-)

What the for-each loop does is select each `<em:VanityUrl>` element matching your XPath expression, make that element the context node for what's inside the for-each (called the *template* even though it's not an `<xsl:template>`), and then instantiate that inner template with the new context node.

When you were continuing to use "$doc/..." inside the for-each loop, you were throwing away the context node, so the for-each was having no effect (except to repeat n times).

Your `<xsl:if test="$doc/...">` statements were evaluating whether there was any such node *in the whole document* instead of under the context element `<em:VanityUrl>`.

The `<xsl:value-of>` statement pays attention to only the first node in the selected nodeset, so you were always getting the value from the *first* `<em:VanityUrl>`, regardless of the context node.

When you started selecting and testing relative to the context node:

```
    <xsl:if test="em:old">
```

everything became better. :-)

You asked for valuable input. For stylistic reasons, you may want to replace your `<xsl:if>` tests with `<xsl:apply-templates>`. (For one thing you'll make @Dimitre Novatchev happy. :-) So

```
<xsl:if test="$doc/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:MappingCollection/em:VanityUrl/em:comments">
  <xsl:comment>
    <xsl:value-of select="$doc/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:MappingCollection/em:VanityUrl/em:comments"/>
  </xsl:comment>
</xsl:if>
```

becomes

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$doc/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:MappingCollection/em:VanityUrl/em:comments" />
```

and then you need a separate template for those:

```
<xsl:template match="em:comments">
  <xsl:comment>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>
```

There are several advantages to doing that. The biggest is that you don't have to duplicate that long XPath expression, which was error-prone if the expression ever needed to be modified. If there are no em:comment elements, the apply-templates will not do anything, so will not emit a comment.

It also modularizes your stylesheet, so that you can modify how em:comments are rendered, separately from wherever they may occur. That may not matter too much in simple XML documents where em:comments occurs in only one place, but it is the style that takes best advantage of XSLT's power. Also note that this modified version will output multiple comments if there are multiple em:comments, which your version will not. Again you probably don't have multiples in the input, so it may not matter.

Similarly for the output attributes:

```
    <xsl:if test="em:old">
      <xsl:attribute name="old">
        <xsl:value-of select="em:old"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
```

can become

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="em:old[1]" />
```

with a separate template

```
<xsl:template match="em:old">
   <xsl:attribute name="old">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the `[1]`, which avoids attempting to output multiple `old="..."` attributes for the same element if the input em:VanityUrl has multiple em:old elements. That would be cause your stylesheet to raise an error. But maybe you *want* to raise an error in that case. If so, you are probably already validating your input XML.

In fact, you can generalize the apply-templates and the template here to apply to all three attributes:

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="em:old[1] | em:new[1] | em:dateAdded[1]" />
```

Again, if any of these elements are not present, nothing will be done for them (no empty attribute will be produced). The template:

```
<xsl:template match="em:old | em:new | em:dateAdded">
   <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

`local-name()` gives us the name of the element, without the namespace prefix.

**Update:**

Another way to handle that would be to use a mode:

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="em:old[1] | em:new[1] | em:dateAdded[1]"
      mode="make-attribute" />

<xsl:template match="em:*" mode="make-attribute">
   <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Then your make-attribute template can be used from anywhere, and the match pattern doesn't have to be updated to match every possible element you might want to make an attribute from.

The only other thing I would say is that the use of namespaces above is confusing...it shouldn't work as-is. E.g. your stylesheet uses this namespace URI for elements like VanityURL:

```
 "http://www.espire.com/tridion/schemas"
```

but the second input document uses this namespace URI for those elements:

```
 "uuid:922EEC29-2DE3-4BA1-A46A-A300CB8FA85F"
```

It doesn't matter that the namespace prefixes are different ("em:" vs. default), but the namespace URIs have to match. I guess VanityURL's namespace URI must have changed, or else your stylesheet wouldn't work...

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input, Everything is fine but the comments are repeating for each element, however I was looking to have one preceding-sibling for each element, Please suggest

Comment: @MKS, please clarify. You're getting multiple output comments for each input em:comment element? or you're getting the same comments over and over? Please edit your question (or answer) to show your updated code and updated output.

Comment: @MKS, also I don't understand what you mean by "I was looking to have one preceding-sibling for each element" - which type of element (name)? in input or output? Please give a sample of your current output vs. desired output.

Comment: @MKS, I think I see... you want each distinct comment to be output only once, instead of repeating the same comment each time it occurs. When your answer said you had resolved the above issue, I thought you meant your XSLT was working as desired. That explains why @Alej is grouping by comment...

Comment: Yes Larsh you are correct, however below answer of @Alej is working fine with second xml, but I have got first xml and from there second xml is generated so my xslt will work for both, in your solution every thing is fine except comments, please suggest

Comment: @MKS, I'm assuming that @Alej is working on his stylesheet. If I come back later and you still don't have an answer I will take a stab at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also!!

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:em="http://www.espire.com/tridion/schemas" xmlns:tcmse="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.1/TcmScriptAssistant" exclude-result-prefixes="em xlink tcmse tcm">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" indent="yes"/>     
  <!-- root match-->
  <xsl:template match="tcm:ListItems">
    <mappings>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tcm:Item"/>
    </mappings>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="tcm:Item">
    <xsl:variable name="doc" select="document(@ID)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$doc/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:MappingCollection/em:VanityUrl/em:comments">
      <xsl:comment>
        <xsl:value-of select="$doc/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:MappingCollection/em:VanityUrl/em:comments"/>
      </xsl:comment>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:for-each select="$doc/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/em:MappingCollection/em:VanityUrl">
      <xsl:element name="mapping">
        <xsl:if test="em:old">
          <xsl:attribute name="old">
            <xsl:value-of select="em:old"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="em:new">
          <xsl:attribute name="new">
            <xsl:value-of select="em:new"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="em:dateAdded">
          <xsl:attribute name="dateAdded">
            <xsl:value-of select="em:dateAdded"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```